# Autodesk Forge Mobile App Multiselection by User

Tags: autodesk-forge

Any ideas on how to allow the user to multiselect objects on a mobile version of the viewer, similar to CTRL-Click within a desktop solution?

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the viewer provides methods like [setClickConfig](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#setclickconfig-what-where-newaction), these are unfortunately only for "mouse clicks", not for "taps".

If you want to achieve the same behavior on touch-enabled devices, you could override the `handleSingleTap` method of the `viewer.clickHandler` like so:

```js
viewer.clickHandler.handleSingleTap = function (event) {
    const result = viewer.impl.hitTestViewport(viewer.impl.clientToViewport(event.canvasX, event.canvasY), false);
    if (result) {
        viewer.toggleSelect(result.dbId, result.model);
    } else {
        viewer.clearSelection();
    }
    return true;
};
```

Comment: I am also wondering about this issue...on a PC, if you hold down Ctrl, you can select a rectangular area.

I would like to be able to do this on the iPad as well, so that when the user presses a button for a custom extension, they can press and hold Ctrl as they do on the PC, or tap and hold it for a long time.