# How to select multiple objects in Autodesk viewer using iPad using my finger instead of PC?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360

If it were a PC, I could press Ctrl to enter multiple selection mode, but on an iPad, there is no Ctrl, so I don't know how to enter multiple selection mode. It may not be possible.

------------------- 3/29 Added ------------------

I am wondering about this issue...on a PC, if you hold down Ctrl, you can select a rectangular area.

I would like to be able to do this on the iPad as well, so that when the user presses a button for a custom extension, they can press and hold Ctrl as they do on the PC, or tap and hold it for a long time.

------------------- 4/7 Added ------------------

```js
        Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => {
            const config3d = {
                extensions: [
                    "Autodesk.DocumentBrowser",
                    "Autodesk.BoxSelection", // I added here too
                ],
            };
            const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(
                document.getElementById("forgeViewer"),
                config3d
            );

            // I Added here
            if (Autodesk.Viewing.isMobileDevice()) {
                viewer.addEventListener(
                    Autodesk.Viewing.EXTENSION_LOADED_EVENT,
                    (event) => {
                        if (event.extensionId === "Autodesk.BoxSelection") {
                            let ext = viewer.getExtension(event.extensionId);
                            ext.addToolbarButton(true);
                        }
                    }
                );
            }

            viewer.start();
            this.viewer = viewer;
            const documentId = "urn:" + urn;
            Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(
                documentId,
                this.onDocumentLoadSuccess.bind(this),
                this.onDocumentLoadFailure.bind(this)
            );
        });
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63921150/autodesk-forge-mobile-app-multiselection-by-user

Comment: I am also wondering about this issue...on a PC, if you hold down Ctrl, you can select a rectangular area.

I would like to be able to do this on the iPad as well, so that when the user presses a button for a custom extension, they can press and hold Ctrl as they do on the PC, or tap and hold it for a long time.

Comment: Regarding Autodesk's viewer API, on a PC, I press Ctrl to enter range selection mode, but I would like to achieve that on an iPad, specifically by holding down the iPad screen for a few seconds to enter that range selection mode.

Comment: Anybody can help me out?

Answer (score 1):

RE: 03/29's question

Mobile devices have no Ctrl button, so we cannot do a similar thing there.

But to activate the box selection on mobile, we could add its button to the viewer toolbar instead. Clicking the button like the snapshot below will do the same thing as you see when holding the Ctrl on PC.

```js
if( Autodesk.Viewing.isMobileDevice() ) {
    viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.EXTENSION_LOADED_EVENT, event => {
        if (event.extensionId === 'Autodesk.BoxSelection') {
            let ext = viewer.getExtension(event.extensionId);
            ext.addToolbarButton(true)
        }
    });
}
```

[image]

BTW, [Changing handleSingleTap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63921150/autodesk-forge-mobile-app-multiselection-by-user) to support activating the box selection would case some problem. The box selection will always be activated when clicking on either object in the viewer.

Comment: I see! If possible, could you give me some more full source code? I've only made a couple of extensions...

Comment: No need to make an extension. We can add the above code snippet to the position above of calling `viewer.start()`. If you're referring to the [old tutorial code](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-viewmodels/blob/master/forgeSample/wwwroot/js/ForgeViewer.js#L47). It should be added before line [#47](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-viewmodels/blob/master/forgeSample/wwwroot/js/ForgeViewer.js#L47)

Comment: Woohoo, I was already using other extensions, so I added them to it and successfully got the range selection tool button to appear on the screen only on the iPad!

But when I pressed that button, I couldn't select the range... Pasted my latest code for your reference

Comment: Oh, it was displayed for a moment, but the button is no longer displayed in the first place. I didn't change anything from the code I posted above... 
Autodesk.Viewing.EXTENSION_LOADED_EVENT is not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the other provided answer would work, as Autodesk.BoxSelection is not loaded for mobile devices, and thus the code is not reachable as the event is never triggered on mobile devices.

I have tried to implement a custom extension that extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension to handle area selection for mobile devices, which has partially worked, however, has some weird behaviour in 2d views. We load BoxSelection extension for non-mobile devices, and load a custom window selection extension for mobile devices.

Can use this for inspiration: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/jsm/interactive/SelectionBox.js

Or: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/custom-window-selection-forge-viewer-simpler-extension

I've tried all 3 Autodesk.Viewing.SelectionType and useGeometricIntersection: true.
It seems when using useGeometricIntersection: false, the extension doesn't load at all.

The best solution I've found so far is useGeometricIntersection: true and REGULAR SelectionType, however, not all elements seem to get selected in 2d Sheets, even when within the range. Range selection in 3d Views seems to work well though.